# What is Difference between Fuerte and Groovy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I'm new to ROS so,I was looking at Distributions of ros.
I found Fuerte and Groovy which were differed in some aspects like

-> No Stacks in Groovy(why?)

->Catkin is Replacement for rosbuild (as rosbuild is creating some problems)

->Rviz config file is changed from .vcg to .rviz ie.., INI format to YAML format

```
          Any other Differences...?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54721/what-is-difference-between-fuerte-and-groovy/) by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stacks have been the unit of release for rosbuild. With catkin, we can release individual packages so stacks are not needed anymore as such.

However in Groovy, some ROS packages are still build with rosbuild, not catkin, and are thus still in stacks. There will be some stacks in future releases as well, until all packages have been migrated to catkin.

Differences are listed in the ROS Groovy release notes, and other articles on the web:
http://robots.net/article/3506.html

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3